# IIS - Setting the physical path of an Application with appcmd

Tags: iis, appcmd

In IIS, I have a web site "Default Web Site" with an application "test2". I want to set the physical path of that application to "E:\temp\out1". That directory already exists.

When I run this in Powershell (as an administrator):

```
appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/test2" -[path='/'].physicalpath:E:\temp\out1
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].  The @position specifier is optional, and be '@start', '@end', or '@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )
```

I have no idea what that means.

Would very much appreciate a working example of using appcmd to set the physical path of an IIS application.

Comment: I usually use this command to change the virtual application physical path:
`appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/app" -[path=’/’].physicalpath:C:\path`
where app is the name of your application and "path to app" is the location where your app is located. In case there are spaces in the application name, or directory structure, use quotes. For example: `appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/Financials" -[path=’/’].physicalpath:"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Financial Web App"`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the command in my question actually works on Command Prompt. However, I tried to run it from a Powershell prompt, and there I got the error message.

I couldn't find a way to run the command from Powershell. In the end, my solution was to write the command to a temporary .bat file, then execute that file from Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If I set my double quotes like this it works from Powershell prompt.

`appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/test2" -"[path='/'].physicalpath:E:\temp\out1"`